# Can I use google to define a route on map and then get time estimate to a location?

Tags: google-maps

For example I have a bus route and bus stops. I would like to set up something where I can check time estimates until bus arrives at a stop (bus pings location). Is this possible with Google or anything else?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes @JasonFel ,you can do that using Google Map service "Waypoints in directions", where you can setup your route of bus from start to end and the stops will be your waypoits, so you can easily find the distance and the approx time between two points, you just need to go through this link,

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints

```
Waypoint Demo: `https://jsfiddle.net/9nb42yhf/1/`
```